# How to get difference between two dates in Oracle and show it as ' x years y month z days'

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to calculate the difference between two dates in Oracle sql and show it in the following format: 'x years y months z days'.

Now I see two ways to achieve this:

The first way is to get the difference in days, and after that, bring it to 'x year y month z days'

The second way is to extract years, month, and days with an extract function.

In the first and second cases, I see problems on how to handle leap-year and difference in month with 30 days versus 31 days.

Is there another, easier way to implement this?

Comment: What definition of "month" do you want to use.  In a non-leap year, what is the difference between Feb 28 and March 31?  You can argue that it's 1 month (last day of the month to last day of the month).  Or you can say that it is 1 month and 3 days.  What about March 31 to April 30?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As another option you could use [the `months_between()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions102.htm), and manipulate the value that gives you into the three parts. For example, with some sample dates:

```
select months_between(date '2015-03-19', date '2012-01-06') as month_diff
from dual;

MONTH_DIFF
----------
38.4193548
```

The number of whole months can be split into three multiples of twelve (i.e. years) with two left over; and the fractional part is the number of days in the partial month, based on a 31-day month.

So you can extract the parts with:

```
with t (start_date, end_date) as (
  select date '2012-01-06', date '2015-03-19' from dual
)
select start_date, end_date,
  trunc(month_diff/12) as year_diff,
  trunc(mod(month_diff, 12)) as month_diff,
  31*(month_diff - trunc(month_diff)) as day_diff
from (
  select start_date, end_date,
    months_between(end_date, start_date) as month_diff
  from t
);

START_DATE END_DATE    YEAR_DIFF MONTH_DIFF   DAY_DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2012-01-06 2015-03-19          3          2         13
```

And then you can use string concatenation to format it however you want, e.g.

```
select trunc(month_diff/12) || ' years '
  || trunc(mod(month_diff, 12)) || ' months '
  || 31*(month_diff - trunc(month_diff)) || ' days' as diff
from (
...

DIFF                   
------------------------
3 years 2 months 13 days
```

Comment: I can't think of a better option in this case. Certainly more accurate than using days and dividing by 365.

Comment: @Mina - no, the docs say "the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month".

Answer (score 0):

I just used this formula and I add some case where a gap of 1 day between 2 dates will result of 2 days diff.

- Case 1 : 08/04/2019 to 30/04/2021 -> 2 years and 22 days
- Case 2 :    08/04/2019 to 01/05/2021 (one day more) -> 2 years and 24
  days (2    days more)

I have corrected the formula :

```
 with t (start_date, end_date) as (
  select date '2012-01-06', date '2015-03-19' from dual
)
select start_date, end_date,
  trunc(month_diff/12) as year_diff,
  trunc(mod(month_diff, 12)) as month_diff,
end_date - add_months(start_date, month_diff) as day_diff
from (
  select start_date, end_date,
    trunc(months_between(end_date, start_date)) as month_diff
  from t
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try 
SELECT months_between('27-Mar-2021','28-Feb-2021') from dual; Output 9.66
SELECT months_between('28-Mar-2021','28-Feb-2021') from dual; Output 1.0
SELECT months_between('29-Mar-2021','28-Feb-2021') from dual; Output 1.03 
SELECT months_between('31-Mar-2021','28-Feb-2021') from dual; Output 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.emp_code,e.emp_name,
        e.emp_dob,
       trunc(months_between(trunc(sysdate),e.emp_dob) / 12) || ' Yrs ' ||
        trunc(mod(months_between(trunc(sysdate),e.emp_dob ),12)) || 'Mon. ' ||
        (trunc(sysdate) - add_months(e.emp_dob,trunc(months_between(trunc(sysdate),e.emp_dob)))) ||'Dys. ' age
  from  employee e
  WHERE e.emp_date_left IS NULL
  ORDER BY 1;
```

I got the correct answer from this query